# Delay is socket.io event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I created an ajax call to the IMBd database

```
// API Key
key = "4dba72b2-7558-4c0f-bd18-9ffcb0999c4e";
// Url
mainUrl = "http://api.myapifilms.com/imdb/top?token="+ key +"&format=json&data=0&start=1&end=250";
// API Call
var request = require('request');

request(mainUrl, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

    // Storing data in an object
    var obj         = JSON.parse(body), //JSON Parser
        movieArray  = obj.data.movies, //Creating Array
        item        = movieArray[randomMovieRank]; //Setting random movie variable
        itermArray  = [item.ranking,item.title,item.year];

    console.log(itermArray);
    io.sockets.emit("serverAnswer", {ranking: itermArray[0], title: itermArray[1], year: itermArray});

  }
});

return false;
```

Followed up by:

```
socket.on("serverAnswer", function(data){
    console.log(data.title);
});
```

The socket.on is called on the client side. The problem I am having is that it is pulling through the data very slowly if at all. The API is working as it is console logging correctly in terminal. But client side it sometimes pulls through ad sometimes doesnt. Is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

Added pastebin: http://pastebin.com/TYHsqBmK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke the *emit* method, your client is not guaranteed connected,you can trigger the ajax event after the client connected or emit specified messages,such as

**the server**:

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    if(movies !== null)
    {
        socket.emit("serverAnswer", {movies:movies});
    }
    else{
        //1.ajax request IMDB resource
        //2.set movies variables
        //3.emit message
    }
});
```

**the client:**

```
socket.on("serverAnswer", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: When you call the if statement, what is movies referring to?

Comment: I have included a pastebin as to show what I have done.

Comment: Not the exact answer I needed but the direction is what got it to work perfectly for me. So thanks! :)